# Horizontal bar chart with just one dimension in Google data studio (looker studio)

Tags: looker-studio

I hava dataset with emails and level of expertise

```
Emails                    Level of expertise 
person1@gmail.com            Beginner 
person2@gmail.com            Intermediate 
person3@gmail.com            Intermediate 
person4@gmail.com            Advanced
person5@gmail.com            Beginner
person6@gmail.com            Intermediate 
person7@gmail.com            Advanced
```

I want to create a horizontal bar chart with just one dimension as shown below

[image]

Right now what I am doing in data studio is

[image]

and that generates this graph

[image]

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new column of data using a calculated field as shown below and then use it as dimension to achieve the intended design chart.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Date,"[\\s\\S]+","Level of expertise")
```

[image]

Comment: This method is good but will prevent you from assigning the order of the dimension values by anything other than metric values. You cannot list them alphabetically for example. To get around this you can add another custom field which is like the following `CASE WHEN Demo Data = 'Beginner' THEN 1 WHEN Demo Data = 'Intermediate' THEN 2 WHEN Demo Data = 'Advanced' THEN 3 END`. Set the default aggregation to MAX then both Sort metrics in the bar chart to this new metric.